# Merging 2 zip files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zip

I have 2 zip files:

file1.zip
file2.zip

I want to compare the two zip files and then only extract the files missing in file2.zip (directory structure intact) so that I can merge them in.

Additionally, is there any way in linux to merge the 2 files (meaning only put files missing in file2.zip from file1.zip).

Thanks.

Comment: Check out `zdiff`.  As far as merging only specific files, I don't know if this is possible in the manner that you want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as 1, 2, 3:
1) unzip file1.zip in new directory
2) unzip file2.zip allowing overwrites in same directory
3) zip files in existing directory